# How to connect oracle DB with ASP.Net

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, .net, oracle

I am connecting Oracle DB with my ASP.Net project but i am getting error "Attempt to load Oracle client libraries threw BadImageFormatException. This problem will occur when running in 64 bit mode with the 32 bit Oracle client components installed"
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DSpt6.png)

[image]

Here is my error screenshot, you can see my error.

Comment: Check this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/92ceczx1(v=vs.85).aspx and http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28844/using_aspnt.htm

Comment: i made a connection string just like u given link but my error is this      "Attempt to load Oracle client libraries threw BadImageFormatException. This problem will occur when running in 64 bit mode with the 32 bit Oracle client components installed"

Comment: Doesn't it specify exactly what's wrong? "This problem will occur when running in 64 bit mode with the 32 bit Oracle client components installed"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well. If u get error as  'Attempt to load Oracle client libraries threw BadImageFormatException'. Follow these links

http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/274404/Attempt-to-load-Oracle-client-libraries-threw-Ba

[BadImageFormatException. This will occur when running in 64 bit mode with the 32 bit Oracle client components installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24104210/badimageformatexception-this-will-occur-when-running-in-64-bit-mode-with-the-32)

Its may help u to solve.